# How to skip the fail test scenario/test step in protractor cucumber

Tags: protractor, cucumber

When I run my test scenarios if any step/scenario fails the execution is stopped. But I want to continue the next test scenarios to execute. Is there any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add `ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true` in your protractor conf.js

```
exports.config = {
    ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true,
```

Comment: Hi Yong, Thanks for your reply. If I use the step in my config.js I am getting below error.                                                                 [02:04:58] W/launcher - Ignoring uncaught error NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: by.cssContainingText("option", "Your Packaging")
[02:04:58] E/launcher - BUG: launcher exited with 1 tasks remaining

Comment: yang I have a question like is there any way to close the browser after each test. I tried with restartBrowserBetweenTests: true, in my config.js but which is closing the browser after each test and am getting below errors. after that.                                                                   [02:51:07] E/launcher - This driver instance does not have a valid session ID (did you call WebDriver.quit()?) and may no longer be used.
[02:51:07] E/launcher - NoSuchSessionError: This driver instance does not have a valid session ID (did you call WebDriver.quit()?) and may no longer be used.

Comment: From the error ` [02:04:58] W/launcher - Ignoring uncaught error NoSuchElementError`,  it indeed ignore uncaught error, the setting take effect.  But I have no idea this message `E/launcher - BUG: launcher exited with 1 tasks remaining`,  We can continueto  run next test with setting until all tests be executed, then exist the launcher.

Comment: I never try `restartBrowserBetweenTests: true`, so have no many experience on it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is by design. If one of the steps in your scenario fails, what would be the value of performing the remaining steps? (Note that each example / scenario should test one thing only.)